# Make Table Cells (Not 3x3, 2x4!) Square?

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

I'm trying to make some response square table cells. I'm aware of the answers to this question, but they all seem to be for a 3x3 grid, I can't find an 2x4 versions. I also don't want it to have to be scrolled, it needs to fit within the menu. It should always be square, if it cannot fit the height, have it be scaled down. I'd like it to be centered horizontally and vertically. How would I go about doing this?
Here's the site in question.
[The Site](https://production-menus.spencerleagra.repl.co/).
You can see how the grid on the right side does fit the height, and width, but isn't square. How can I fix this?

```css
.menu{
  background: #222222;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  /*left: 50%;*/
}
.menu.right{
  width: 25%;
  height: 70%;
  /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  top: 5%;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  /*display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  */
  /*grid-template-columns: auto auto;*/
  /*grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
  */
  /*grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr) / repeat(2, 1fr);
  padding: 5px;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#statwrap{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 5px;
}
#stattab{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  border-spacing: 10px 10px;
}
#statbody{

}
.statcell{
  background: #333333;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu right">
  <!--
  <div class="stat one"></div>
  <div class="stat two"></div>
  <div class="stat three"></div>
  <div class="stat four"></div>
  <div class="stat five"></div>
  <div class="stat six"></div>
  <div class="stat seven"></div>
  <div class="stat eight"></div>
  -->
  <div id="statwrap">
    <table id="stattab">
      <tbody id="statbody">
        <tr>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const adjustSquare = () => {
    let squareWidth = document.querySelector('.menu.right').offsetHeight / 4;
    document.getElementById('stattab').style.maxWidth = (squareWidth * 2) + 'px';
}

document.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (document.readyState == 'interactive') {
        adjustSquare()
    }
}

window.onresize = adjustSquare
```

```css
.menu {
    background: #222222;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
.menu.right {
    width: 25%;
    height: 70%;
    top: 5%;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    justify-content: center;
}
#statwrap {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 5px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
#stattab {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    border-spacing: 10px 10px;
}
.statcell {
    background: #333333;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.statcell .square {
    padding-top: 100%;
}
.statcell .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu right">
  <div id="statwrap">
    <table id="stattab">
      <tbody id="statbody">
        <tr>
          <td class="statcell">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
          </td>
          <td class="statcell">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="statcell">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
          </td>
          <td class="statcell">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="statcell">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
          </td>
          <td class="statcell">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="statcell">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
          </td>
          <td class="statcell">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to scroll down, is there a way to make them fit the height too?

Comment: If you want them to fit height then they wouldn't fit width. One or other. You have set width and height of parent element to % value which is different for if you use different screen if you want to use 100% of width and height of parent element then there is no way to make them square as long as you doesn't set parent element to fixed height and width so they will fir squares for example `width: 200px; height: 300px` this will fit 6 squares 100px by 100px (margins, gaps and paddings ommited)

Comment: I think I should've mentioned, if they can't fit width, they should be centered, and scaled down. Essentially, I guess, what mine is doing, except, the width should be the same as the height.

Comment: By that i meant thet they will not take full width to preserve aspect ratio.

Comment: Is there a way to make them scaled down to fit the height, but still be squares? That is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Adding a bit of javascript to the mix is the last thing that comes to my mind. I have updated my answer

Comment: Ah, so there's no way to do it with pure CSS? It also now won't scale up.

Comment: I don't think that it will be possible (with my knowledge) to do this without js. If you want to scale it with browser then apply same function to windows.resize (updated answer)

Comment: Ah, that works, almost perfectly. All it needs now is for the table itself to be centered in the menu.

Comment: just add `justify-content: center; align-items: center;` to `statwrap` (updated)

Comment: Actually, one, final thing. Is there a way to make it also do this, for vertical centering?

Comment: Is that possible, or no?

Comment: add to `.menu.right` property `justify-content: center;`

Answer (score 1):

Inside a cell , you can use a floatting pseudo with a vertical padding of 100% . it will take td's width as reference and will stretch it to be at least a square.

A table cell will grow anyway to match the heigth of content if it goes beyond your initial square

```css
.menu.right {
  width: 25%;
  height: 70%; 
  max-width:40vmin;
  max-height:90vmin;
  min-width:0;
  float: right; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border:solid;
}

#statwrap {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 5px;
}

#stattab {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  border-spacing: 10px 10px;
}

#statbody {}

.statcell {
  background: #333333;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

.statcell::before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu right">
  <!--
  <div class="stat one"></div>
  <div class="stat two"></div>
  <div class="stat three"></div>
  <div class="stat four"></div>
  <div class="stat five"></div>
  <div class="stat six"></div>
  <div class="stat seven"></div>
  <div class="stat eight"></div>
  -->
  <div id="statwrap">
    <table id="stattab">
      <tbody id="statbody">
        <tr>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
          <td class="statcell"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This uses scrolling, I want it the table to be scaled down to fit the height.

Comment: @FoxGAMING_NTF , okay, that was not specified in the question, in that case, you may look at vmin value to set a max-height and a max-width . Snippet updated, but , again , you did not specified the real context, so that might not be what you need ;) ... square turn to be rounded in that small snippet view :) ... maybe another point to clarify. Have fun coding anyway.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I updated the question. What's weird is that it seems to work here, but not when I add it to my site.

Comment: @FoxGAMING_NTF you should complete your snippet with enough code to reproduce your real situation  ;)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to have to add everything. I'll try to get it to do what it's doing here.